# PHP mail() with ssmtp

Tags: php, ubuntu, gmail, ubuntu-12.04, sendmail

I have a very peculiar problem... I have a Ubuntu Server 12.04 with LAMP installed and ssmtp installed and configured properly.
Now I can send mails from my system(P.C), but when i upload my project to a web host(DigitalOcean)  my gmail sends me notification telling "Suspicious login detected and has been blocked , please change password" .

This is my ssmtp.conf

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=xyz@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

# The full hostname
hostname=xyz@gmail.com

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES

UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=xyz@gmail.com
AuthPass=xyz
```

And DigitalOcean server is located in shanghai,china and i am in india. How do i make it work ???

Answer (score 0):

You should consider logging in to gmail account using DigitalOcean ip - if you have a ssh or telnet you can easilly tunnel the traffic.

Gmail will ask you for some info about the account before allowing smtp connections. Just answer them and after you finally log in, smtp should work fine.

Comment: Do you have a ssh to your server?

Comment: then using putty([tutorial](http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/)) in windows or linux terminal connect to your ssh server with local tunnel: `ssh -R8585 sharad@digitalocean.com`. Then change your internet connection configuration in your browser to use proxy and select SOCKS with host 127.0.0.1 and port 8585